# Configuring theano to use libgpuarray

Tags: python, config, theano

I'm trying to switch theano to `gpuarray` backend now.
This [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html) says that to use `cuda` backend I write

```
device=cuda
```

In `.theanorc`
but it does not specify what to write to use `gpuarray`, and that is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `gpuarray` backend just lets you target both OpenCL and CUDA devices so you'll still need to explicitly target a CUDA or OpenCL device in the `.theanorc` file. Under the hood it's still using OpenCL or CUDA so the device target remains the same, `gpuarray` simply provides an extra layer of abstraction that allows using either.

See [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html) for further documentation.